# SQL row with multiple available data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to make SQL database (MSSQL) for a webshop prototype
Each product can have different types, for example: **wood plane** which can be in different sizes, 30x30, 30x50, 50x100 etc.. **And each size should have it's own price**
But sizes are only displayed in product page, not in all products page
How do I implement that correctly?

I am thinking to have just one table **Products** and make cell called **IsChild** and **ParentID** and just reference all childs to their parents (**Wood plane 50x50** is child of **Wood Plane** and won't be displayed in product list but will be displayed in **Wood plane** product page as it's other size
Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your proposal looks good. But this question type is not well suited for SO

Answer (score 1):

Why not have a product table and a product description table?  This way you could select from products on your main product page by selecting from `product.Product` only, and then show more granular data on the product description page by joining to `product.ProductDescription`.  Very simplistic example:

**product.Product:**

```
╔═══════════╦═════════════╗
║ ProductId ║ ProductName ║
╠═══════════╬═════════════╣
║         1 ║ Wood Plane  ║
╚═══════════╩═════════════╝
```

**product.ProductDescription:**

```
╔══════════════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦═══════╗
║ ProductDescriptionId ║ ProductId ║   Size   ║ price ║
╠══════════════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬═══════╣
║                    1 ║         1 ║ 30 x 30  ║ 10.00 ║
║                    2 ║         1 ║ 30 x 50  ║ 20.00 ║
║                    3 ║         1 ║ 50 x 100 ║ 30.00 ║
╚══════════════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩═══════╝
```